# Bash: Find matching text and replace next line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, pattern-matching

**Alert:** I have seen these sort of questions before on stackoverflow. I searched a lot. Followed solutions but could not solve the problem.

I have a variable **$NEW_FILE** which gives a value of 
**nothing(./location/file1)]**
when you do echo $NEW_FILE

**I have a file test1.txt which contains:**

Hello, World!

This is not working

I don't know a thing about sed and awk

**Now I want to search for word - working
and add a new line after that contained in $NEW_FILE
So desired output would be:**

Hello, World!

This is not working

nothing(./location/file1)]

I don't know a thing about sed and awk

**How do i achive this in a bash using sed or awk?**

This is what i tried:
awk '/working/ { print; print $NEW_FILE; next}1' test1.txt

**This gives output:**

Hello, World!

This is not working

$NEW_FILE

I don't know a thing about sed and awk

Can someone help me with this?

I think we also have to consider the forward and backward slashes in NEW_FILE variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NEW_FILE` is probably a bash-variable and therefore not a variable in awk. So, either let bash do the expansion:

```
awk '/working/ { print; print "'$NEW_FILE'"; next}1' test1.txt
```

or pass/set the variable from the command line:

```
awk -v NEW_FILE="$NEW_FILE" '/working/ { print; print NEW_FILE; next}1' test1.txt
```